# decomposition of a number in c++

Tags: c++, numbers

I don't have a code , I'm only asking how to start. Well the user enters the number (as an example the number will be 437).Decomposition units are (50,10,1) like in a banking system.Lets come back to the example 437 , the output will be 50*8(because the result is 400), then 10*3(... 30) and finally the number 7 will be 1*7. How to start? and what if instead the number 437 there will be 1101? How to tell to the code to stop?

Comment: Integer division plus modulo operator are your friends!

Comment: @stackoverblown i know if im using "number/10" i can exclude the last digit, and if im using "number%10" im taking the last digit.

Comment: same works for other bases. `number / x` tells you how many units of `x` are in `number` and `number%x` tells you what is the remainder. `10` is no special case, it is just the base most commonly used

Comment: did you get your original question deleted, so you then copy it almost verbatim? `1101` used to be `1111`, 437 used to be 156, etc.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with c++. Before writing any code you need to know what code to write. Did you already take pen and paper to calculate the result for some examples?

Comment: @MPops yes:))) i'm still searching for the answer

Comment: @idclev463035818 ohhh god, I need some steps...

Comment: step1: take pen and paper and calculate the result by hand for some examples. Thats nothing someone else can do for you and without that you wont get a understanding of the problem and its solution

Comment: @MPops 50 * 8 (8 bills with a value of 50), 10 * 8 (8 bills with a value of 10) and 1 * 7 (7 bills with a value of 1)

Comment: Okay, now I want 487 dollars, but the only bills you have available or `[33, 19, 1]`. How many of each? (sorry for the seeming nagging, but understanding this conceptually will be important)

Comment: @MPops 12 bills with a value of 33, 4 bills with a value of 19 and 15 bills with a value of 1. oooohhhhhhh wait :))

Comment: @MPops thanks for your patience, i've done the code, sometimes im dumb asf.

Comment: @idclev463035818 thanks for your tip . I succeeded.

Comment: @MPops I was thinking about something more complicated, but actually it’s so easy, I don’t know why sometimes my brain just doesn’t work

Comment: you are welcome, btw step 2 is: generalize what you did for the examples to find an algorithm and step 3: write the code, but I guess you already made some progress ;)

Comment: @CristianZaharia You could actually be more efficient. Because you can have 14 bills of 33, 1 bill of 19, and 6 bills of 1. I'm not sure exactly how you found 12, but 487/33 = 14 with a remainder of 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you are a bank teller, and someone is withdrawing a very specific amount of cash. They request 111111 dollars. What is your brain doing in order to tell you to stop giving them cash? Will you give this person infinite money? Will you give him no money? Literally, ask yourself HOW you would break this persons money into smaller bills. Then explain to a child who doesn't know math how to do it.

Then tell the computer to do it via code. The computer is better than a child in that they have no logical intuition on tackling problems, but they follow instructions exactly, and they do math very very well. So, pretend the computer (your program) is a child who will do exactly what you say, and tell it how to give a customer the cash they request.

**If you do not know how you, as a bank teller, would solve this problem, then stop coding and go learn the math first.** Solving simple programming problems like this requires at least this level of math proficiency.

Answer (score 1):

I won't be able to give you the C++ code right now, but logically I would suggest the following:

You have a set of divisors, in your example that would be 50, 10 and 1. You simply go in order and divide your dividend with each - the answer for each will be the integer portion (not rounded). If there is a remainder, then the remainder gets divided by the next.

So, in kinda pseudocode:

(divisors are 50, 10, 1 - dividend is 437):

// get number of 50's

num50s = 437 / 50;

remainder = 437 - (437 / 50);

// get number of 10's

num10s = remainder / 10;

remainder = remainder - (remainder / 10);

ETC...

num50s, num10s...are what you're looking for.

Now, this can be written a lot better and more efficiently, but hopefully it gives you the idea.

BTW - a number like 1101 would be the same. If you include 100 as part of your breakdown, then the above example works, but instead of starting with dividing by 50 and getting the remainder, you start by dividing by 100. Hope this helps.